Using bulkCreate as a bulk update in Sequelize?
I'm working on an express.js project that uses Sequelize as the ORM, and postgres as the database engine.
In Sequelize, you can do an upsert for multiple rows like this:
models.Package.bulkCreate(
  packagesData,
  {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['status', 'delivery_date']
  }
)

But what if you do this ONLY for updating existing rows? Is it a good way to do a bulk update? Is it too slow?
Some time ago I implemented a raw bulk update query in the project that looked something like this:
UPDATE package
SET status = t.updated_status, delivery_date = t.updated_delivery_date
FROM (VALUES
    ('delivered', '<some date>'),
    ('out_for_delivery', '<some date>')
) as t(row_id, updated_status, updated_delivery_date)
WHERE id = t.row_id

Is something like that even worth doing, considering you could use bulkCreate?
The biggest issue with using bulkCreate to update to me is that you could potentially create unwanted rows, especially if you allow nulls in a lot of fields. This could get solved by only using it with data that was previously retrieved with a select query, but that error could still be introduced in the future if there are changes in the code.
What alternative is the best? Is there something I'm not seeing? Any other options?

Sequlize has bulkUpdate on the query interface, but it's built for setting the same values for all rows that fit a condition, I'm not sure if this really fits your needs.

Unless I'm missing something, that bulkUpdate only updates those rows with the same data, in this case I need to update each row with different data

AFAIK PostgreSQL doesn't have bulk update operation, only bulk insert (Do you know any other DBMS that can do that?) so Sequelize also can't
